# AS3 - Formula to convert decimal coordinates to DMS format (Degrees, Minutes, Seconds)

Tags: actionscript-3, formula

I've got my AIR app that displays the current location of the user like:

lat: -22.14354
long: 166.4256

I'm looking for a formula that can convert these coordinates to the format of "Degrees, Minutes, Seconds". The result would be, for this example:

lat: -22° 8' 36.744"
long: 166° 25' 32.16"

Where could I find this formula in AS3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fairly simple: The [integer part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) of the absolute number is the *absolute* value of the "Degrees" and the [fractional part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part) (i.e: `n-Math.floor(n)`,) will be used for the values of "Minutes" and the "Seconds".

When you multiplied the "fractional part" by `60`, then, the integer part of the resulting value is the amount of "Minutes". Similarly, the fractional part of the resulting value (i.e: `mm - Math.floor(mm)`,) multiplied by `60`, would be the value of the "Seconds" to which I've applied a custom rounding routine on (i.e: the function of `myRounding()` :)

```
function toDMS(dec:Number):String {
    var n:Number = Math.abs(dec);

    var D:Number = Math.floor(n)*(dec > 0 ? 1 : -1);
    var mm:Number = (n-Math.floor(n))*60; // The fractional part * 60
    var M:Number = Math.floor(mm);
    var S:Number = myRounding((mm - Math.floor(mm))*60, 4);

    return D+"° "+M+"' "+S+"\"";
}

function myRounding(num:Number, decimals:uint):Number {
    var m:uint = Math.pow(10, decimals);
    return Math.round(num * m) / m;
}

trace(toDMS(-22.14354)); // -22° 8' 36.744"
trace(toDMS(166.4256));  // 166° 25' 32.16"
```